# Нужна ли запятая перед "и", и почему, каким правилом регулируется?

Tags: запятые, перечисление

Нужна ли запятая перед "и", и почему, каким правилом регулируется?

> Сборка мебели  в Новосибирске, Кемерово, Томске, Красноярске,
> Барнауле, Новокузнецке и на расстоянии до 150 км. от них
> осуществляется бесплатно.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Сборка мебели в Новосибирске, Кемерово, Томске, Красноярске, Барнауле, Новокузнецке **и на расстоянии до 150 км от них** осуществляется бесплатно.*

Запятая не ставится перед соединительным союзом И, **замыкающим  ряд** однородных членов (обстоятельств).

2. В данном случае можно использовать соединительный союз А ТАКЖЕ, чтобы выделить последний однородный член. Перед этим союзом запятая ставится:

*Сборка мебели в Новосибирске, Кемерово, Томске, Красноярске, Барнауле, Новокузнецке, **а также  на расстоянии до 150 км от них** осуществляется бесплатно.*

Союз А ТАКЖЕ обычно используется, если перечисление  велико, например:
На заседании выступили психологи, психотерапевты, педагоги, филологи, а также студенты и социальные работники.

[http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#311](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#311)

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.